# saving values of one array into another array using for loop statement using MATLAB 2014

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

It may be a little bit complicated to explain for me but I'll try my best. If it's not quite clear then please ask me again for clarifications. So, I have some 3-4 array to process in this problem. First array is `centroids` (mx2 double). My second array is `point3D` (437x517x3 single). Now using the values of `centroids` I want to find out the corresponding values of `point3D` and store these values in another array named `co_ord`. For example say in `centroids` for X1 and Y1, I want to extract corresponding values in `point3D` and so on up to Xm and Ym and store them into `point3D` for further use. I got `centroids` array through Image processing and `point3D` array from stereo vision.

**Code** which I tried is as

```
load('C:\Users\Naseeb\Desktop\centroids.mat'); % load centroids file
load('C:\Users\Naseeb\Desktop\point3D.mat'); %load point3D file
centroids = ceil(centroids); % change values into integer
x = cell(size(centroids,1),1); % create array X for storing first column values
y = cell(size(centroids,1),1); % create array Y for storing second column values
 i = cell(size(centroids,1),1);
for i = 1:size(centroids,1) 
   for row = 1:size(centroids,1)
    for column = 1:size(centroids,2)
        x{i} = centroids(size(centroids,1),1); % store values of first column into array X
        y{i} = centroids(size(centroids,1),2); % store values of second column into array Y
        co_ord = point3D(x{i},y{i},:); % store values into co_ord file
    end
   end 
end
```

**For clarification of this I'm explaining my problem with simple example.**
let's say centroids matrix is (3x2) and point3D is (5x5x3). centroids matrix = [2 3; 3 4; 4 5]. In this 2 and 3 represent pixel values in horizontal and vertical directions of an image respectively. Similarly (3,4) and (4,5). Also point3D is multidimensional matrix of 5x5 by 3 in which 5x5 represent pixels and corresponding to these pixels values, there are 3 values which I have to extarct and store in an output array. For example for centroid (2,3), in point3D matrix corresponding to (2,3), values may be (0.2, 0.7, -0.11). Similarly, for (3,4) and (4,5) values may be (0.1, 0.4, -0.21) and (0.35, -0.27,0.6). Now all these values I have to store in output array.
output array looks like
[0.2 0.7 -0.11; 0.1 0.4 -0.21; 0.35 -0.27 0.6]

I hope it may become more clear now.
Thanks

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you are trying to do. Why do you use cells? Why do you loop on the `column` and `row` variables? (Seems like you're doing a lot of times the same calculation). Why do you overwrite `co_ord` at every iteration?

Comment: Hi BillBokeey,
Thanks for your attention. What I want to solve is like this. I have one array called centroids in which 2 columns (X and Y) are present. Number of rows may vary in this array. Now corresponding to these X and Y values there are values in point3D array. So I want to extract those  values and store them into another array called co_ord. I do not want to overwrite in co_ord but want to store every value in co_ord. I tried above coding but that's not working purposefully. So i need help.

Comment: Hi Naseeb. Can you add to your post a very simple example with for example : a `3x2` Matrix centroids, a `5x5x3` matrix point3D and the corresponding output? It would help set things very clear so that we can help you do what you want

Comment: Hi BillBokeey, As you suggest me to explain my problem with example so I explain my problem in question with example. Please look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various methods in so many days I reached to answer of above question. Thanks for all those who tried to solve this problem.

```
load('C:\Users\Naseeb\Desktop\centroids.mat'); % load centroids file
load('C:\Users\Naseeb\Desktop\point3D.mat'); %load point3D file
centroids = ceil(centroids); % change values into integer

%%
null=[];
Co_ordinates=[];  % final matrix where Co_ordinates will be stored
for step=1:3;
    temp=[];
    for k=1:length(centroids);
        null=point3D(centroids(k,1),centroids(k,2),step);
        temp=[temp null];
    end
    Co_ordinates=[Co_ordinates; temp];
    step=step+1;
end
```